# SQL: I cant find the error in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

It's telling me that the table **clientescrm** doesn't exist. I can't find the error.

```
select
 a.cuit,
 a.duplicates,
 c.Idclientecrm
from
(
   select
      replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit,
      count(cuit) as duplicates
   from clientescrm
   group by cuit
   having count(cuit) > 1
) a,
clientescrm c
where
a.cuit= replace(replace(c.cuit, '-', ''),'_','')
```

Thnx for the help

Comment: Have you selected your database?

Comment: @Pietro - Verify the table exists and you can query from it with a basic select.  The Query is fine, albeit ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should change the way you join on the tables. A query like this is the **standardised** way of writing a syntax.

```
SELECT
 a.cuit,
 a.duplicates,
 c.Idclientecrm
FROM
(
   SELECT
      replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit,
      count(cuit) as duplicates
   from database.clientescrm
   group by cuit
   having count(cuit) > 1
) a
JOIN database.clientescrm c ON a.cuit=replace(replace(c.cuit, '-', ''),'_','')
```

The reason for why its not found is most likley that the current database in use is wrong, or less likley, that the table doesnt exists.

Make sure you change `database.` to the name of your database where the table `clientescrm` is located.

Comment: It's not any more efficient, both methods result in the same execution plan.  It's just easier to human read.

Comment: i used your query, but now It's telling me that cuit is ambigous

Comment: That means it doenst know which cuit to use. Meaning there is columns with the same name. Im looking at the cuit and they have the table alias in front of it.

Comment: Using explicit `JOIN`s is **not** "more efficient" - but it is indeed the better way to do it.

Comment: So if its the better way to do it, wouldnt that means its a more efficent way. ;) Efficent doesnt nessecarily mean its better performance. No worries lads, i amneded my statement